# excel, merge two columns between static column and list of numbers

Tags: excel, merge

column A, static value:

```
302_000
302_000
302_000
```

column B, list of numbers, separated by . (except is there is only 1 number in the cell):

```
222. 57. 5.
389. 390. 
412
```

column c, after merge:

```
302_000_222, 302_000_057, 302_000_005
302_000_389, 302_000_390
302_000_412
```

any recommendations?

Comment: Excel VBA will make this a little easier by making use of the `Split` function

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?  If not Office 365 or Office 2019 then vba is the only way to concatenate the results into one column without many helper columns.

Comment: is your 412 in second table supposed to be followed by a period? Or is that consistent with your actual data? The last digits on your first 2 values have the last followed by a dot so its not really clear

Comment: I am using Office 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C2 put the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,A2&"_"&TEXT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(B2),LEN(TRIM(B2))-1),".",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(LEFT(TRIM(B2),LEN(TRIM(B2))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(B2),LEN(TRIM(B2))-1),".",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),"000"))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

Comment: as long as per-format the single number with a period at the end.

Comment: Yes. I missed the bottom on I am afk but can fix tomorrow.

Comment: @Unicorn this will do the job `TEXTJOIN(", ",,A1&"_"&TEXT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",REPT(" ",100)),100*ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MAX(1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","")))))-99,100)),"000"))`, presume your source data is *clean* without the need to **TRIM**, and confirm the formula by pressing **CSE** :) Pretty much same logic as Scott's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
=A1 & SUBSTITUTE(B2, ". ", ", "&A1)
```

This prefixes the value with the constant, and then replaces each dot with a comma and that constant

Comment: This will not return the correct number format as the OP wants the last digits to be three digits.

Comment: Right. I missed that